# Statistic to use to measure intersection probability in set of elements

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Being two sets of elements:

```
set a: ele1, ele2, ele3, ele4, ele5, ele6, ele7
set b: ele3, ele4, ele8, ele9
```

And is intersection:

```
intersection a_b: ele3,ele4
```

So there are ele3, and ele4 that appear in the two sets, and the others doesn't.

I can compute the similarity of the two sets, by similarity measures, like Jaccard:

```
Jaccard index = len(intersection_a_b)/ len(a)+len(b)-len(intersection_a_b)
```

However,
Those similarity measures asumes that "elements" have an uniform distribution and set1 and set2 comes from the same population.

In my case, set1 and set2 comes from different populations and there are some "elements" more frequent than others **for each population**, for example:

```
set a
element - rel freq

ele1 0.1
ele2 0.9
ele3 0.3
...

set b
element - rel freq

ele3 0.8
ele4 0.9
...
```

Even More, The efective size of populations are different, like set a comes from population a(10000 efectives) and set b commes from population b(6000 efectives)

Questions:

How i can compare those two sets in case of only different element frequency but same population size?

How i can compare those two sets in case of different population size and different element frequency?

---

An example:

Imagine that i'm working on semantics. I've two dictionary of concepts:
*Dictionary of alcoholic* drinks and *dictionary of hobbies*

Inside each dictionary there are terms, like *guitarrist or photographer* and *beer and rhum*

I get money for the goverment and i go to annotate my first dictionary of drinks, by the people who drink it. I make a survey in my city that have 5000 habitants, and ask for to all those 5000 persons.

Inside *rhum* and *beer* there are:

```
Rhum: Pepe,bertuccio, Arnold, florence, and jessy, luis
Beer: Pepe, Arnold, florence, sica, luis and tiago
```

There are people that like to drink more things than others.

For example: Luis like 30 out 60 drinks in my dictionary, so Luis appear in 50% of the terms, florence only like 3 drinks out of 60, so they appear in 5% of the drinks. So, my set *Beer* looks like

```
Beer
terms       rel. freq.

Luis        0.5
Arnold      0.2
florence    0.05
Jessica     0.6
```

I get more money from the goverment and i do a second survey to annotate my dictionary of hobbies, but, this time i've less money so i cannot ask all the population (5000 persons) and i only reach to annotate 3200 persons out of 5000.

My term guitarrist looks like:

```
guitarrist: Luis, florence, toto, picasso.
```

Also, there are people that have more hobbies than others, and the table in this case looks like this:

```
Guitarrist
terms       rel. freq.

Luis        0.8
Picasso     0.2
florence    0.05
```

I want to do pairwise comparisions between the two terms, for example, i want to compare Beer drinkers to guitarrist, in order to know who drinks what.

The sets (terms) to compare looks like this:

```
guitarrist: Luis, florence, toto, picasso.
Rhum: Pepe,bertuccio, Arnold, florence, and jessy, luis
intersection: Luis, Florence.
```

I can use Jaccard Index to compare it, by this ecuation:

```
Jaccard index = len(intersection_a_b)/ len(a)+len(b)-len(intersection_a_b)
```

In my case:
    Jaccard index = 2/ 6+4-2 = 2/8 = 0.25

How ever there are people that is more informative than others(Florence versus Luis) are they are more specific(florence only likes one drink and have less hobbies), So i think i cannot use Jaccard index in this case.

Comment: When you write `union a_b: ele3,ele4`, surely you meant _intersection?_  The union of the two sets has $9$ elements and not $2$ elements.

Comment: I don't really understand your model here. When you say "relative frequency", is that a property within each "set" or is it in the distinct populations that they're drawn from? Are `ele3` from $A$ and `ele3` from $B$ the same elements, but they are weighted differently within $A$ and $B$, or is there something different going on?

Comment: relative frequency is in for each population, ele3 from A and ele3 from B are the same "element". I have change a little the text, but fell free to change.

Comment: I still don't really understand what you're saying with the sets coming from different populations. Can you maybe give some details about your real application?

Comment: Done :), i think is ussefull now